# Emit() a Signal to a different class isn't working

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am currently working on a GUI with PyQt5 (I'm a noob when it comes to python and Qt) and I need to emit a Signal from one class to another.

I read about this and googled around and also found a lot of helpful stuff but it still doesn't work for me.

This is my code-dummy:

Class Nr.1:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import Class2


class Class1(QWidget):
    eventButtonPressed = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.Class1Btn = QPushButton('Button')
        self.Class1Edit = QLineEdit(self)

        self.Class1Btn.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

        # Layout stuff to mimic my real program
        self.Class1Grid = QGridLayout(self)
        self.Class1Grid.addWidget(self.Class1Btn)
        self.Class1Grid.addWidget(self.Class1Edit)
        self.groupBoxLayout1 = QGroupBox(self)
        self.groupBoxLayout1.setLayout(self.Class1Grid)

    def clicked(self):
        self.eventButtonPressed.emit(self.Class1Edit.text())
```

Class Nr.2:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import Class1


class Class2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.Class1OBJ = Class1.Class1(self)
        self.Class1OBJ.eventButtonPressed.connect(self.StuffWhenSignalIsEmitted)

        # Layout stuff to mimic my real program
        self.Class2Edit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.Class2Grid = QGridLayout(self)
        self.Class2Grid.addWidget(self.Class2Edit)
        self.groupBoxLayout2 = QGroupBox(self)
        self.groupBoxLayout2.setLayout(self.Class2Grid)

    def StuffWhenSignalIsEmitted(self, text):
        print('Text from Class 2 Widget: {}'.format(self.Class2Edit))
        print('Text from Class 1 Widget: {}'.format(text))
```

My Main Window:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import Class1
import Class2


class MainWindow(QWidget, QApplication):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.Class1OBJ = Class1.Class1()
        self.Class2OBJ = Class2.Class2()

        self.WinLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.WinLayout.addWidget(self.Class1OBJ.groupBoxLayout1)
        self.WinLayout.addWidget(self.Class2OBJ.groupBoxLayout2)
        self.setGeometry(1100, 300, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("GUI")
        self.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want the program to print the statements from the StuffWhenSignalIsEmitted method when I press the button (if it is possible). So I want to print what is in the LineEdit from Class one, as well as what is in the LineEdit from Class2.

Comment: typo: add `self.startButton()` after `super().__init__()` because you have never created the button that you press and add `self.classOneOBJ.show()` after `self.classOneOBJ = ClassOne()` since you have never shown the new window.

Comment: Yeah thank you. I updated the code to make my question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you think that if a variable has the same name in different classes it is the same variable, because they are not, they are different objects. The self.Class1OBJ in Class2 is different from the self.Class1OBJ in MainWindow.

So the solution is just to create a single self.Class1OBJ:

Class2.py

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Class2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Layout stuff to mimic my real program
        self.Class2Edit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.Class2Grid = QGridLayout(self)
        self.Class2Grid.addWidget(self.Class2Edit)
        self.groupBoxLayout2 = QGroupBox(self)
        self.groupBoxLayout2.setLayout(self.Class2Grid)

    def StuffWhenSignalIsEmitted(self, text):
        print('Text from Class 2 Widget: {}'.format(self.Class2Edit))
        print('Text from Class 1 Widget: {}'.format(text))
```

**main.py**

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import Class1
import Class2


class MainWindow(QWidget, QApplication):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.Class1OBJ = Class1.Class1()
        self.Class2OBJ = Class2.Class2()
        # add the following line
        self.Class1OBJ.eventButtonPressed.connect(self.Class2OBJ.StuffWhenSignalIsEmitted)

        self.WinLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.WinLayout.addWidget(self.Class1OBJ.groupBoxLayout1)
        self.WinLayout.addWidget(self.Class2OBJ.groupBoxLayout2)

        self.setGeometry(1100, 300, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("GUI")
        self.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you that explains it! So that means that even though the text in the LineEdit is always there it is bond to one Object? I can not access the text that is written there with the help of any Object of Class 2?

Comment: @FreddyKly 1. It was another object. 2. Each object is independent, by analogy means that a class refers to the abstraction of similar elements, for example human beings are a class, and we all have a name Do you think you can get my name by asking for the name to another human being? Well, no. So the class **is the** human being, and the object **is a** human being.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class ClassTwo(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.classOneOBJ = ClassOne(self)                # + self
        self.classOneOBJ.eventButtonPressed.connect(self.StuffWhenSignalIsEmitted)

        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.classOneOBJ)

    def StuffWhenSignalIsEmitted(self, text):
        print('it worked ->{}'.format(text))
        # and do stuff with instance variables of an existing object

class ClassOne(QWidget):
    eventButtonPressed = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit() 

        self.Btn = QPushButton('Button')            
        self.Btn.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.Btn)

    def clicked(self):
        self.eventButtonPressed.emit(self.lineEdit.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
     app = QApplication(sys.argv)
     main = ClassTwo()
     main.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Your code works perfectly but my adaption still does not do what I want it to (I'm probably not understanding a certain concept) I will edit my post and add new code that will hopefully make the problem more clear.